# JQuery mobile radio button controlgroup width

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I am trying to style jquery mobile radio button controlgroup with diferent width buttons.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you just have to override the CSS, [see docu](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html)

> **Overriding themes**
>
> The themes are meant as a solid starting point, but are meant to be
>   customized. Since everything is controlled by CSS, it's easy to use a
>   web inspector tool to identify the style properties you want to
>   modify. The set of of theme classes (global) and semantic structural
>   classes (widget-specific) added to elements provide a rich set of
>   possible selectors against which to target style overrides. We
>   recommend adding an external stylesheet to the head, placed after the
>   structure and theme stylesheet references, that contain all your style
>   overrides. This allows you to easily update to newer versions of the
>   library because overrides are kept separate from the library code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is links to jquery plugins
http://line25.com/articles/jquery-plugins-for-styling-checkbox-radio-buttons
and here
http://www.itsalif.info/content/demo-ezmark-jquery-plugin/
and image radio button
http://www.thheuer.com/2011/10/jquery-plugins-image-radio-buttons/